# How to Implement Hibernate 6 Set-Aggregate Function listagg() in Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm having a hard time implementing Hibernate 6's new set-aggregate function **`listagg()`** and I couldn't find any resource online with a clear example. Here's the documentation:

`JpaExpression<String> listagg​(JpaOrder order, JpaPredicate filter, JpaWindow window, jakarta.persistence.criteria.Expression<String> argument, jakarta.persistence.criteria.Expression<String> separator)`

Parameters:

order - order by clause used in within group

filter - optional filter clause

window - optional window over which to apply the function

argument - values to join

separator - the separator used to join the values

Returns: ordered set-aggregate expression

Any help is appreciated :)